# How to assert value in login response in soapUI?

Tags: groovy, soapui, zato

I have a login request and I want to assert a value from the response.

Here is this response:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="https://TUI.io/ns/20110812">
   <soap:Body>
      <login_resp>
         <zato_env>
            <cid>K07FKWJTWZMCNFJJBNDQVMZTW4TQ</cid>
            <result>TUI_OK</result>
         </zato_env>
         <item>
            <response>{"timestamp": "2015-11-30T17:05:37Z", "data": {"file": null, "token": "16e5fd", "endpoints": [{"label": "app1", "branc": [{"url": "/app1/v1.0/", "name": "test", }]}}, "success": true}</response>
         </item>
      </login_resp>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Now I want to assert:

```
file = null
endpoints = [{"label": "app1", "branc": [{"url": "/app1/v1.0/", "name": "test", }]
```

I tried this:

```
// check for RequestId element in response
def holder = new XmlHolder( messageExchange.responseContentAsXml )
assert holder["//ns1:file"] != null
```

I have not been able to resolve class `XmlHolder`.

Comment: Is the response *really* a combination of JSON in XML? If yes, could you also ask the dev WTF they were thinking?

Comment: Agree with @SiKing. @Templog Log, add the `import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder` on top of  the script to resolve issue you mentioned.

Comment: And using the current respone, first you need to read the string from `//*:item/*:response`. Then convert it to json object inorder to read the value of file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the groovy script, which will log the profile, endpoints

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder
import net.sf.json.groovy.JsonSlurper
def soapResponse='''
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="https://zato.io/ns/20130518">
   <soap:Body>
      <login_resp>
         <zato_env>
            <cid>K07FKWNDQVMZTW4JTWZMCNFJJBTQ</cid>
            <result>ZATO_OK</result>
         </zato_env>
         <item>          
         <response>{"timestamp": "2015-11-30T17:05:37Z", "data": {"profile": null, "token": "1225555-sd18-4895-a037-d81ae2e273e2", "endpoints": [{"label": "app6", "branches": [{"url": "/app7/v1.0/", "name": "test", "api_version": "1.0", "label": "test"}], "appname": "app5"}, {"label": "app4", "branches": [{"url": "/gui/v1.0/", "name": "est", "api_version": "1.0", "label": "test"}], "appname": "gui"}, {"label": "app3", "branches": [{"url": "/app3/v1.0/", "name": "test", "api_version": "1.0", "label": "test"}], "appname": "app3"}, {"label": "app2", "branches": [{"url": "/app2/v1.0/", "name": "test", "api_version": "1.0", "label": "test"}], "appname": "app2"}, {"label": "app1", "branches": [{"url": "/app1/v1.0/", "name": "test", "api_version": "1.0", "label": "test"}], "appname": "app1"}]}, "success": true}</response>
         </item>
      </login_resp>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
'''
def holder = new XmlHolder(soapResponse)
def response = holder.getNodeValue('//*:response')
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response)
log.info json.data.profile
log.info json.data.endpoints
```

Similarly, you may query using `.` and json property any value as shown above.

For ex, to get `timestamp` - you may use -`json.timestamp` and to get `token`, `json.data.token` etc.,

EDIT: Based comments - intended to use in script assertion to handle response dynamically.

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder
import net.sf.json.groovy.JsonSlurper
def soapResponse = messageExchange.responseContent 
def holder = new XmlHolder(soapResponse)
def response = holder.getNodeValue('//*:response')
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response)
log.info json.data.profile
log.info json.data.endpoints
```

Comment: xml taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34025950/groovy-replace-data-from-file-with-space/34026927?noredirect=1#comment55810458_34026927

Comment: thanks a lot Rao, you helped me and also i found a solution with scritp assertion but your solution is better for me.

Comment: By the way, you can use script assertion too for dynamic handling of response instead of groovy script. To do that, you may just remove 3rd line and replace it with `def soapResponse = messageExchange.responseContent`. I made it as above because it is easy to test with fixed content as we do not have such environment

Comment: i just need to replace  def soapResponse by def soapResponse= new File("C:\\temp4\\response.txt"), i will try

Comment: I mean entire xml i.e., change from `def soapResponse = '''<soap:Envelope>....</soap:Envelope>` to `def soapResponse = messageExchange.responseContent`. And use the above snippet in script assertion.

Comment: Did update the answer for script assertion to hand dynamically each response.

Comment: it works for me, i used the script assertion and replace the code as u mentioned. thank you