# groovy replace data from file with space

Tags: groovy

i want to replace string from a file.
i have a line like this:

```
qwe{data:"dede-dddd-ssss",login:"user",display:"screen"},abc,xyz
```

i want to replace all string starting from data to login with spaces

i try this i can only replace the string, is there a way to replace with a starting and endpoint for string?

```
def source = new File("c:\\sq\\file1.txt") 
def dest = new File("c:\\sq\\file2.txt") 

def fileText = source.text
def filedest = dest.text
for ( index in 1..9 ) {
    fileText = (fileText =~ /data/).replaceFirst("")
```

Answer (score 2):

This code has an anchored version (to `{`) of the regex:

```
def fileText = '''\
qwe{data:"dede-dddd-ssss",login:"user",display:"screen1"},abc,xyz
...
qwe{data:"data2",login:"user2",display:"screen2"},abc,xyz
...
qwe{data:"data3",login:"user3",display:"screen3"},abc,xyz\
'''

fileText = fileText.replaceAll(/(?<=\{)\s*data:[^,]+,\s*login:[^,]+,/ , '')
println fileText
```

Output:

```
qwe{display:"screen1"},abc,xyz
...
qwe{display:"screen2"},abc,xyz
...
qwe{display:"screen3"},abc,xyz
```

Try also in the [online groovy web console](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5177290749116416)

**UPDATE**

If a understand correctly your request: this following code read the input text from `source` (`c:\\sq\\file1.txt`) and put the modified text into destination file `dest` (`c:\\sq\\file2.txt`):

```
def source = new File("c:\\sq\\file1.txt") 
def dest = new File("c:\\sq\\file2.txt") 

dest.write(source.text
  .replaceAll(/(?<=\{)\s*data:[^,]+,\s*login:[^,]+,/ , '') )
```

Comment: it doesn't work for after execution, the file keep the same data

Answer (score 1):

If you want it in the files, then you can try below, and find the updated data in test2.txt:

note:please update the file paths as per your environment

Courtesy @GsusRecovery for regex

```
def fileContent = new File('/tmp/test.txt').text
def replacedContent = fileContent.replaceAll(/(?<=\{)\s*data:[^,]+,\s*login:[^,]+,/ , '')
def newFile = new File('/tmp/test2.txt')
newFile.write(replacedContent)
```

Comment: i tried, i did not remove data, all data are present in test2.txt file

Comment: the file content is too long i will try to attach

Comment: Rao, @TemplogLog: thanks for the addiction, i've modified the code to fit the OP request

Comment: have a look here http://hastebin.com/tomijohonu.xml i explained what i want to keep from the response file, only profile and endpoints, the rest should be removed, i'm trying since yesterday.

Comment: @TemplogLog, I remember now, you put another question related to this based on the attachment. You can easily do that using json rather than text replacing. Probably, if I get chance, will update other question if I can find its reference.

Comment: @GsusRecovery, no worries, and thank you for your updates.

Comment: I was talking about this question posted by @TemplogLog http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34005588/how-to-assert-value-in-login-response-in-soapui

Comment: Yes Rao, you are right, i'm trying for hours and hours, i cannot succes with this and i'm not familiar with regex, this part is very difficult, as u can there is json inside xml, i tried everything with java and groovy. i really need help, thank you

Comment: @TemplogLog, is there anything still you looking for  as none of the answers accepted ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear on what your desired outcome is. If you want to remove the "data" and "login" fields and the corresponding values from the input strings, such that your example of:
`qwe{data:"dede-dddd-ssss",login:"user",display:"screen"},abc,xyz`
becomes:
`qwe{display:"screen"},abc,xyz` then you can easily use a regex to do this.

The following code:

```
​String str = """qwe{data:"dede-dddd-ssss",login:"user",display:"screen"},abc,xyz"​​""
str = str.replaceFirst("​​​​​​​​​​​​​data.*login:\".+?\",", '')
println str​
```

Prints `qwe{display:"screen"},abc,xyz`

Comment: thank you mbaird, i replaced the two last line of my code by:              fileText = fileText.replaceFirst("​​​​​​​​​​​​​data.*login:\".+?\",", '')   it did not work for me, i'm trying to do it in a file.