# Transfer property from login to logout in saopui pro

Tags: soapui

i'm trying to transfer the token number from the login response to logout request using the Transfer property in soapui pro.

response:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="https://in.io/ns/20110517">
   <soap:Body>
      <login_resp>
         <in_env>
            <cid>1JMRXxxxDWF31PXC0EFQ</cid>
            <result>IN_OK</result>
         </in_env>
         <item>
            <response>{"timestamp": "2015-12-07T14:14:35Z", "data": {"profile": null, "token": "1a66k111-3177-0000-000b-aed1478c8309", "endpoints": [{"label": "app1", "branches": [{"url": "/app1/v1.0/", "name": "ext-", "api_version": "1.0", "label": "ext"}], "appname": "app1"}]}, "success": true}</response>
         </item>
      </login_resp>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Then i Source i put this:
declare namespace ns1='https://in.io/ns/20110517';
//ns1:login_resp[1]/ns1:item[1]/ns1:response[1]

i Target i put this:
declare namespace gar='test.in.v1.soap';
//gar:logout_req[1]/gar:token[1]

The result:
It took the entire line from timestamp to true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able set the token value to a property from groovy script itself without using the additional `property transfer` test step.

It is already provided script in the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34005588/how-to-assert-value-in-login-response-in-soapui/34027875#34027875), and amending the additional change that is required to the new requirement.

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder
import net.sf.json.groovy.JsonSlurper
def soapResponse = messageExchange.responseContent 
def holder = new XmlHolder(soapResponse)
def response = holder.getNodeValue('//*:response')
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response)
log.info json.data.profile
log.info json.data.endpoints
//appending to previous answer
log.info json.data.token
//set it to test case property
context.testCase.setProperty('TOKEN', json.data.token.toString())
```

Use `${#TestCase#TOKEN}` where the value of token is needed in the following test step.